# Why does Windows 7 Disk Management prevent me from reducing Disk size?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a  Disk with 3 Partitions:
Disk1:  1 2  3  [unallocated]

1. I deleted partition 2
2. I reduced 3 in size but not enough.
3. I wanted to reduce 3 more but it now won't let me reduce it very much. (I have about 600 GB available (free) on that disk.

Why not?
Does it only support ONE resize of a Partition?

Comment: OK, so would maybe GParted work?

Comment: And do submit that as an Answer, it sounds like the correct one.

Comment: I have never used gparted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk management is limited on shrink due to where files are located in that partition, you would need to use a 3rd party disk software to shrink it more, as they can move files during the shrink process as DM cannot. Back up important files before shrinking with 3rd party software.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well. I did the following: Used windows Defrag.  This will order the blocks of the HD and then you'll be able to shrink partition.

Comment: Defrag can usually take care of this, but if there are files flagged with the `S` (system) attribute, then they may be immovable, like swap files.  If you have a system file near the end of the partition, then `defrag` won't move it unless you remove the attribute (only do this if you know what you're doing) or otherwise safely move the file elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

"Mini-tools Partition Wizard" home edition (free)

gparted (system tool) on any linux live disk

or just use c'man' to delete and recreate part's

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.